# Why is "k" in the output of Sum[Log[k]/k^k, {k,1,Infinity}]?

Tags: bugs, summation

Fixed in **11.3**

---

```
NSum[Log[k]/k^k, {k,1,Infinity}, WorkingPrecision->50]
(* 0.219947267975228664843531307905860703797097130 *)
```

But

```
Sum[Log[k]/k^k, {k,1,Infinity}]
(* -(PolyLog^(1,0))[0,1/k] *)
```

What does "k" in the result? Bug ?

Comment: It's really `Times[-1,Derivative[1,0][PolyLog][0,Power[k,-1]]]`. I get the same result on 11.1.1.0 on Mac. I'd call it a bug.

Comment: Problem continues thru v11.2 on Mac

Comment: This is quite obviously a bug. `NSum[Log[k]/k^k, {k, 1, Infinity}]` evaluates to `0.219947`, and it obviously shouldn't have a $k$ in the output. I'm adding the tag. (V10.0.1 on Mac OSX).

Comment: BTW, [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5BLog%5Bk%5D%2Fk%5Ek,+%7Bk,1,Infinity%7D%5D) gives the same troublesome result.

Comment: Versions 5.2.0 and 8.0.4 give the same wrong result, moreover, the result from 5.2.0 contains the variable "K$18" instead of "k".

Comment: Problem also exists with v11.2 on Windows 10, 64-bit.  I added `GenerateConditions -> True` but nothing changed.  Using `Method` with the first two strategies in the documentation returned unevaluated, while with the last three strategies returned the wrong answer as before.  Certainly, a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fyi,

In 11.3 the result is returned as unevaluated. So the issue was bypassed. Much better to return unevaluated, than return something not correct.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Compare to version 11.2

[image: Mathematica graphics]