# Why is `k` in the output of `Sum[Log[k]^2/k^k, {k,1,Infinity}]`?

Tags: bugs, summation

The following sum converges to a constant. It would be much better to return unevaluated than to return something incorrect.

```
 Sum[Log[k]^2/k^k, {k, 1, Infinity}]
 (* (Zeta^\[Prime]\[Prime])[k] *)
```

What does `k` in the result?

Same with `Sum[Log[k]^3/k^k, {k, 1, Infinity}]` etc.

One similar bug has already been fixed in 11.3, see [Why is "k" in the output of Sum[Log[k]/k^k, {k,1,Infinity}]?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/161704/why-is-k-in-the-output-of-sumlogk-kk-k-1-infinity), but this not. Tested with versions 13.2, 13.1, 12.3.

Comment: "What does k in the result?" -- I assume you mean why is `k` there as in the title? I think you must know already. Do you really want this question answered, or are you asking for help with something else? If you are trying to report a bug, report it to WRI. The community decided long ago that this site is not a place to report bugs.

Comment: `NSum[Log[k]^2/k^k, {k, 1, Infinity}]` evaluates to `0.173225`

Comment: Seems fixed in V13.3.1 or at least partially. It returns unevaluated.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a fix, of sorts (V13.2.1), if that is what is wanted:

```
(* unset cached result -- will give an error message if no
   chached result, which can be ignored *)
Sum`SumParserDump`sumParserEvaluate[
   k^-k Log[k]^2, {{k, 1, \[Infinity]}}, {}] =.;

Internal`InheritedBlock[{Sum`InfiniteSumDump`InfiniteLogarithmicSeries},
 Sum`InfiniteSumDump`InfiniteLogarithmicSeries[
    Log[Sum`InfiniteSumDump`k_]^
     Sum`InfiniteSumDump`n_ Sum`InfiniteSumDump`k_^
     Sum`InfiniteSumDump`m_, {Sum`InfiniteSumDump`k_, 
     Sum`InfiniteSumDump`min_, \[Infinity]}] /; ((IntegerQ[
         Sum`InfiniteSumDump`m] && Sum`InfiniteSumDump`m < -2) || ! 
       NumericQ[Sum`InfiniteSumDump`m]) && (IntegerQ[
       Sum`InfiniteSumDump`n] && Sum`InfiniteSumDump`n >= 1) && 
    IntegerQ[Sum`InfiniteSumDump`min] && 
    Sum`InfiniteSumDump`min >= 1 =.; 
 Sum`InfiniteSumDump`InfiniteLogarithmicSeries[
    Log[k_]^n_*k_^m_, {k_, min_, \[Infinity]}] /;
     ((IntegerQ[m] && m < -2) ||
        (Print["here"]; FreeQ[m, k] (* fix *)&&
          ! NumericQ[m])) &&
      (IntegerQ[n] && n >= 1) && IntegerQ[min] && min >= 1 :=
  (-1)^n Derivative[n][Zeta][-m] - Sum[Log[k]^n*k^m, {k, 1, min - 1}];

 (*foo=DownValues[Sum`InfiniteSumDump`InfiniteLogarithmicSeries];*)
 
 Sum[Log[k]^2/k^k, {k, 1, Infinity}]
 ]
```

> [image]

No bug, but no result either.  The `Print["here"]` statement may be omitted, of course.  I put it in to help identify the fix. If you change `k^k` to `k^7` or `k^y`, it still works (`Zeta''[7]` or `Zeta''[y]` resp.) as in Roland's answer.

Comment: Wow! How do you find this function ``Sum`InfiniteSumDump`InfiniteLogarithmicSeries ``?

Comment: Thanks! Quite interesting!

Comment: [Oops, forgot a double backtick.] First ``Block[{Sum`print = Print}, Sum[Log[k]^2/k^k, {k, 1, Infinity}]]``. Then based on the output, ``?Sum*`*ogarithm*``.  Then I used `Trace` to see if/how it was called and ``GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions`` to inspect the code. There are many internal debugging hooks that end in `Print` or `print`.

Answer (score 2):

```
  Sum[Log[x]^2/x^7,{x,1,Infinity}]
      (Zeta^\[Prime]\[Prime])[7]

     Sum[Log[n]^2/n^y,{n,1,Infinity}]/.{y->1.2}
     249.99
      Sum[Log[x]^2/x^1.2,{x,1,Infinity}]
     249.99
```

Seemingly, the procedure differentiates between base $x$ and exponent $x$ in $x^x$ and makes the exponent a variable pattern.